# How to get Maximum date from Django Model Query?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I have a `Student` model in Django which has following fields `Id, Status, Marks, End Date`.
When I am doing following query-

```
records = list(Students.objects.filter(status__in=["Active"])
    .values('id', 'marks', 'end_date')
```

Then this is the value that I am getting -

```
[{'id':'450', 'marks':'30', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'450', 'marks':'60', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'450', 'marks':'80', 'end_date':None},
 {'id':'452', 'marks':'51', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'452', 'marks':'27', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

Now, my requirement is to get sum of all marks and max date for same `Ids`. For exa for above result set the output that I want is this -

```
[{'id':'450', 'marks':'170', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 7, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)},
 {'id':'452', 'marks':'78', 'end_date':datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 3, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]
```

I have tried the following code to get this output -

```
records = list(Students.objects.filter(status__in=["Active"])
    .values('id', 'end_date')
    .annotate(marks=Coalesce(Sum('marks'), 0),
            ))
```

Above code is giving me sum value but I am not able to get Max date. I tried adding `end_date=Coalesce(Max('end_date__date'), 0)` into annotate function but this is throwing this error -

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Anyone have idea how to get the Max date using annotate method or is there any other way of doing it?

Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: The problem is the `Coalesce` part, since that does not work properly on a datetime field, why do you need to coalesce in the first place?

Comment: I normally need to calculate average and sum for that `Coalesce` works perfectly fine. This is first time I am using for date. What is other approach of doing it?

Comment: But `end_date=Coalesce(Max('end_date__date'), 0) makes no sense, since `end_date__date` is a `date` object, not a number, hence `0` is non-sensical.

Comment: Yes I understand I shouldn't use 0 and that does not make any sense. In that place I can use a date object, but that doesn't solve the problem. Do you know any other method of doing it?